# entityManager.persist(object) NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, glassfish-3, entitymanager

I have been struggling all week to learn Java EE. I am building a REST api using Restlet 2.0, Spring, Hibernate, and Maven through Netbeans 7.2. Now I am at the point where whenever I make a service call that tries to persist data to the database, the following method throws a `NullPointerException`

```
@Override
public void save(T object) {
    entityManager.persist(object);
}
```

From looking at the code, the following piece is supposed to inject the `entityManager`

```
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEngityManager(EntityManager entityManger) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

I found the link [EntityManager injection results in NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108446/entitymanager-injection-results-in-nullpointerexception). But I am too new to understand how to implement it in my code. Also, I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.

Will someone please help with some code sample?

EDIT/UPDATE:

Below is the persistence.xml file I am using. I am running MySQL and Glassfish. Should I save it under `WEB-INF` which is where `persistence-context.xml` is OR under `src/main/resource` which is where `hibernate.cfg.xml` is?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.mysite.restapi.RestletChildApplication</class>
    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
                    value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myname"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mypassword"/>
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I am running `java EE 6`

Comment: Where is the injection coming from? Per the line `<class>com.mysite.restapi.RestletChildApplication</class>`, am I supposed to create an instance of `EntityManager` in the  class `com.mysite.restapi.RestletChildApplication`?

Answer (score 0):

```
setEntityManager
```

instead of

```
setEngityManager
```

you have typo.

Create persistence unit, like here
[java.net](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/persistence/persistence-example.html#Using_Netbeans_Java_SE_Example)

and inject EntityManager by persistence unit's name

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="your_unit_name")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it and rerun, etc. But I still get the `NPE` at `entityManager.persist(object);`

Comment: is `persistence-context.xml` the same as `persistence.xml`? I have the former but not the latter. Also my `persistence-context.xml` was generated by netbeans. Should I additionally create a `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: First time listen about `persistence-context.xml`. You must have `persistence.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Incase of Java EE 5, `@PersistenceContext(unitName="your_unit_name")` can be used only container managed objects like EJB or Servlet.

Incase you want to create EntityManager object in a non-container managed object like a plain java class use refer the following sample.

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    if (emf == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("your_unit_name");
    }
    return emf;
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManager entityManager = null;
    if (null != emf)
           entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

    return entityManager;
}
```

Incase of Java EE 6, you may refer CDI - Context and Dependency injection on how to inject EntityManager.

Comment: I am running  `EE 6`. Does my `persistence.xml` file above look correct? I juste edited the post to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are useful. The very short version is that likely your EntityManager is null. The call itself shouldn't throw a null pointer exception.